# Can't figure out the right way to break a long parameter to multiple lines

Tags: vba, web-scraping, line-continuation

I've created a script to fetch json response from a website. To get the response I had to issue post http requests along with appropriate parameters. The script is doing fine.

The `payload` that I've used within the script is substantially long. It could have been longer.

> Now, my question is, how can I break such long line to multiple lines?

This is how I've tried:

```
Sub GetJsonResponse()
    Const URL = "https://api.pcexpress.ca/product-facade/v3/products/category/listing"
    Dim payload$

    payload = "{""pagination"":{""from"":2,""size"":48},""banner"":""loblaw"",""cartId"":""702da51e-a7ab-4f54-be5e-5bf38bd6d7a2"",""lang"":""en"",""date"":""09062021"",""storeId"":""1032"",""pcId"":null,""pickupType"":""STORE"",""enableSeldonIntegration"":true,""features"":[""loyaltyServiceIntegration"",""sunnyValeServiceIntegration""],""inventoryInfoRequired"":true,""sort"":{""topSeller"":""desc""},""categoryId"":""27985""}"
    
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "POST", URL, False
        .setRequestHeader "content-type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
        .setRequestHeader "x-apikey", "1im1hL52q9xvta16GlSdYDsTsG0dmyhF"
        .send (payload)
        Debug.Print .responseText
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You can paste your JSON into a worksheet cell (nicely formatted) and read it from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the & concatenation to join smaller parts. I would personally examine the json structure and then decide on logical breaks (within reason), then transfer to a text editor and use regex/ find and replace to generate the new strings to concatenate based on your chosen line breaks.

Below you will see most lines have `payload = payload & "` at the start and `"` at the end, after the break indicated by the `,`.

Of course, also replacing inner `"` with `""`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetJsonResponse()
    Const URL = "https://api.pcexpress.ca/product-facade/v3/products/category/listing"
    Dim payload$

    payload = "{""pagination"": {""from"": 2,""size"": 48},"
    payload = payload & """banner"": ""loblaw"","
    payload = payload & """cartId"": ""702da51e-a7ab-4f54-be5e-5bf38bd6d7a2"","
    payload = payload & """lang"": ""en"","
    payload = payload & """date"": ""09062021"","
    payload = payload & """storeId"": ""1032"","
    payload = payload & """pcId"": null,"
    payload = payload & """pickupType"": ""STORE"","
    payload = payload & """enableSeldonIntegration"": true,"
    payload = payload & """features"": [""loyaltyServiceIntegration"", ""sunnyValeServiceIntegration""],"
    payload = payload & """inventoryInfoRequired"": true,"
    payload = payload & """sort"": {""topSeller"": ""desc""},"
    payload = payload & """categoryId"": ""27985""}"

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "POST", URL, False
        .setRequestHeader "content-type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
        .setRequestHeader "x-apikey", "1im1hL52q9xvta16GlSdYDsTsG0dmyhF"
        .send payload
        Debug.Print .responseText
    End With
End Sub
```

This fits with how I re-arranged this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

---

As you noted in the comments, you can absolutely split the string into pieces and continue the line with the [line continuation character](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/program-structure/how-to-break-and-combine-statements-in-code) `_`.

Comment: It seems I can achieve the same like ***[this](https://pastebin.com/kKRWrH4i)*** as well.

Comment: Absolutely. Trick is to find what works for you. And things you can do easily with regex in a text editor are usually a good idea if dealing with a large string.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Windows Clipboard API functions from here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/windows-api/send-information-to-the-clipboard

You can copy text to the clipboard and do something like:

```vb
Sub ClipboardTextToVbaString()
    Dim s As String, arr, e, rv As String, i As Long, n As Long
    s = GetClipboard()  'read text from clipboard
    If Len(s) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    arr = Split(s, vbCrLf)
    rv = "s = "
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        e = Replace(arr(i), """", """""")
        rv = rv & """" & e & """ "
        If i < UBound(arr) Then
            If n < 20 Then
                rv = rv & " & vbCRLf &  _" & vbCrLf
                n = n + 1
            Else
                rv = rv & " & vbCRLf" & vbCrLf & "s = s & "
                n = 0
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    'Debug.Print rv
    SetClipboard rv  'set the modified text back into the clipboard for pasting
End Sub
```

Not very thoroughly-tested but you get the idea: something for your personal.xlsb file...
Note this is more aimed at formatting multi-line text into a VB-compatible format - not really for breaking up long single lines, which I guess was your original form.

Comment: I like the practicality of this. Clearly I have not deal with sending long enough strings in the past. + Are these declarations artefacts (sep, multi)? Guessing sep is for other uses cases to specify delim? multi a flag for splitting on more than one delim?

Comment: Yes I didn’t clean up my abandoned paths….   Will tidy it